# Find area of a triangle

Tags: geometry, area

$AB = 30, AD = 60, AEFG$ and $ABCD$ are rectangles. $AG = 20, GF = 40.$ Given that area of $\triangle ABE = 360 \text{ cm}^2$, find area of $\triangle ADG$.

I tried to show $\triangle AGD$ similar to $\triangle AEB$, but it doesn't seem right and I am not sure how to proceed.

[image]

Comment: A straightforward if inelegant solution suggests itself in the law of cosines since $\text{m}\angle GAD = \text{m}\angle EAB$.

Answer (score 2):

The angles $GAD$ and $EAB$ are equal. The area of the triangle $EAB$ gives the sin of this angle (the area is the product of side lengths times the sin divided by $2$). Given that sin you can compute the area of the triangle $GAD$.

Comment: Thank you, besides using trigonometry, what other method can I use?

Comment: You do not use trigonometry here. Only the fact that the area of a triangle is the product of two side lengths times the sin of the angle between them divided by 2,

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try this if you are not allowed to use any trigonometric functions.

Draw the heights of $\triangle ABE$ and $\triangle ADG$, $EQ$ and $GP$ in the picture respectively. We have $AE=40,AG=20$. Since
$$\angle EAQ=\angle PAG\Rightarrow\triangle AQE\sim\triangle APG\Rightarrow\dfrac{QE}{PG}=\dfrac{AE}{AG}=2, $$
one gets
$$\text{Area}_{AGD}=\dfrac{1}{2}AD\cdot PG=\dfrac{1}{2}AD\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}QE=\dfrac{1}{2}AD\cdot\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{2\times\text{Area}_{ABE}}{AB}=360\text{ cm}^2. $$

Comment: Hi, can I ask how you get $QE = \dfrac{2\times\text{Area}_{ABE}}{AB}=360\text{ cm}^2?$

Comment: @Joe Just write down the formula for $\text{Area}_{ABE}=\frac{1}{2}AB\cdot QE$.

Comment: ok got it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Those 2 triangles are not similar.

---

**Hint:** Area of triangle is $ \frac{1}{2} AG \times ADD \times \sin \angle GAD$.

**Hint:** $\angle GAD \equiv \angle ???$

Comment: Thank you, besides using trigonometry, what other method can I use?